# Constructor call in c# class

Tags: c#, constructor

Hi  I am doing a c# course and cannot understand the constructor call subject.  I get errors with this and have been watching videos but I can't get it to work, I keep getting the error:  "E2.Student.Student(string, string)' cannot call itself"

When I try to create a constructor with 2 parameters I get this error, as I understand it this constructor with the 2 parameters that I am trying to create inherits from the constructor beneath it with the 4 parameters?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace E2
{
    class Student
    {
        string fullName;
        string course;
        string email;
        string phonenr;
        enumUniversity university;
        enumSubject subject;

        public Student()
        {
        }

        public Student(string fullname,string course) : this (fullname,course) =======>THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR
        {
        }

        public Student(string fullname, string course, string email, string phonenr, enumUniversity university, enumSubject subject)
        {
            this.fullName = fullname;
            this.course = course;
            this.email = email;
            this.phonenr = phonenr;
            this.university = university;
            this.subject = subject;
        }

        public void PrintInfo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} Course {1} email {2} phonenr {3} univ {4} subject {5}", fullName, course, email, phonenr, university, subject);
        }
    }
}
```

**Example from my learning content:**

```
public Dog(string name)
: this(name, 1) // Constructor call
{
}
// Two parameters
public Dog(string name, int age)
: this(name, age, 0.3) // Constructor call
{
}
// Three parameters
public Dog(string name, int age, double length)
: this(name, age, length, new Collar()) // Constructor call
{
}
// Four parameters
public Dog(string name, int age, double length, Collar collar)
{
this.name = name;
this.age = age;
this.length = length;
this.collar = collar;
}
```

Comment: If your intention is that the 2 parameter constructor should rely upon the 6 parameter constructor, *what values* should be used for `email`, `phoner`, etc?

Comment: Supply the default values: this (fullname,course, "default email", "default phone", university.Val, subject.Val)

Comment: Currently you want your constructor with 2 parameters to call constructor with 2 parameters(itself). Provide more parameters to call another constructor.

Comment: Patrick Hofman I did look at the example you supplied but it is so complex, I watched videos, I tried the examples in my learning content but never did anybody say that I must add default values for the other parameters.  I've added the example from my learning content to the question and nowhere does it state to use default paramaters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You let the constructor call itself using ctor chaining.  This offcourse, is not possible since it would lead to the world into some kind of infinite loop :)

The way to do this, is that you'll need to call the constructor with all the other arguments, like ths:

```
        public Student() : this(string.Empty, string.Empty)
        {
        }

        public Student(string fullname,string course) 
            : this (fullname,course, string.Empty, string.Empty, default(enumUniversity), default(enumSubject))
        {
        }

        public Student(string fullname, string course, string email, string phonenr, enumUniversity university, enumSubject subject)
        {
            this.fullName = fullname;
            this.course = course;
            this.email = email;
            this.phonenr = phonenr;
            this.university = university;
            this.subject = subject;
        }
```

Comment: Ok thank you I understand now.  Will accept as correct answer asap.